# Applying for a US visa interview at another country as a non-resident

Tags: visas, covid-19

I am an international PhD student at a US university. Due to the COVID-19 embassy closure, my spouse can not apply for an F-2 dependent visa at the local embassy to travel to the US. However, she can apply for a visa at the US embassy in another country. She will have to apply for a visa for our 3 years old child. However, she would like to travel alone to the other country to attend the visa appointment. My question is: can she apply for the visa for him without him being present? Since his passport will not be stamped at the airport (since he won't leave my home country as my spouse travels abroad to attend the interview), will this pose any problem at the airport when they both travel to the US?